# All commands and ssh connection stopped working after hplip installation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, command-line

I am trying to configure a print server on an Ubuntu Server 16.04

After the installation of HPLIP package all the commands I try to execute on the command line stopped working.

I have rebooted the system and it didn't work. I checked my .bashrc and .profile files and they are OK.

Now, as my commands on the command line are not working I cannot undo the installation or try anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried purging the HP package (**hplip**)?

Comment: My command line is not working. I can’t purg the package. I can’t do anything.

Comment: Can you bring up a terminal outside of Webmin?

Comment: Yes, the first image is of a terminal opened on webmin. Any command I try doesn’t result in any output

Comment: Can you ssh to the server and run commands from there?

Comment: No. I eill try to log in ditectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102056/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-guidupas).

Comment: Unfortunately, even accessing the system directly, nothing was working. The solution was to make a backup of everything and reinstall the system completely.